# error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type

Tags: c++, error-handling, find, std

I'm trying to make a program that solves an image based maze. While programming the part where I connect the vertices in the maze to create edges (I want to make the maze into a graph) I got this error. It seems to be because of the `std::find` but I don't know what is wrong. I've tried searching the question already, but I can't seem to find what I want.

Here's the part of my code with the problem:

```
// the struct used to define the coordinates
struct pixelCoord {
int x, y;

pixelCoord(int paramx, int paramy) : x(paramx), y(paramy) {}};

{...}

std::vector<pixelCoord> vertices;

// adding vertices as pixel coordinates on my image
{...}

// initializing graph
Graph g(vertices.size());

// searching for and adding edges to graph
for (size_t k = 0; k < vertices.size(); k++) {
    int l = 1;
    while (maze_bmp.getPixel(vertices[k].x, (vertices[k].y + l))[0] == 255) {
        ptrdiff_t next_vertex_pos = std::find(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), pixelCoord(vertices[k].x, (vertices[k].y + l))) - vertices.begin();
        //if (next_vertex_pos >= vertices.size()) {
        //  g.addEdge(k, next_vertex_pos, l);
        //  break;
        //}
        l++;
    }
```

Also `maze_bmb.getPixel(...)` is just a function to return the RGB values of the pixel for comparing and not much else.

Thank you!

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, then please copy them, as text and in full and complete, and paste them without modifications into the question body. Also mark out, with a comment, *where* the error is. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is also very helpful.

Comment: That's not enough information. What's in `vertices`?

Comment: I updated it to add more information. I hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: You should implement operator== for pixelCoord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the "==" operator for a class/struct that you have implemented, you need to overload the "==" operator for that class. You can check this link to learn more about overloading the operators: [Operator Overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)